# In Google Form, how do you embed a Google Map so that the user can pinpoint their location?

Tags: google-maps, google-forms

In Google Form, I am asking for the location of a person. To make it more accurate, instead of making them input an address, I like to be able to let the user pinpoint their location in Google Maps and then save the latitude and longitude in the spreadsheet.

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Google Forms.